# How do I determine open/closed state of a dijit dropdownbutton?

Tags: dojo, status

I'm using a dijit DropDownButton with an application I'm developing. As you know, if you click on the button once, a menu appears. Click again and it disappears. I can't seem to find this in the API documentation but is there a property I can read to tell me whether or not my DropDownButton is currently open or closed?

I'm trying to use a dojo.connect listener on the DropDownButton's OnClick event in order to perform another task, but only if the DropDownButton is clicked "closed."

THANK YOU!
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I couldn't find such a property either, so I ended up adding a custom property `dropDownIsOpen` and overriding `openDropDown()` and `closeDropDown()` to update its value, like this:

```js
myButton.dropDownIsOpen = false;
myButton.openDropDown = function () {
    this.dropDownIsOpen = true;
    this.inherited("openDropDown", arguments);
};
myButton.closeDropDown = function () {
    this.dropDownIsOpen = false;
    this.inherited("closeDropDown", arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may track it through its CSS classes. When the DropDown is open, the underlying DOM node that gets the focus (property focusNode) receives an additional class, *dijitHasDropDownOpen*. So, for your situation:

```
// assuming "d" is a dijit.DropDownButton
dojo.connect(d, 'onClick', function() {
    if (dojo.hasClass(d.focusNode, 'dijitHasDropDownOpen') === false) {
        performAnotherTask(); // this fires only if the menu is closed.
    }
});
```

This example is for dojo 1.6.2, since you didn't specify your version. It can, of course, be converted easily for other versions.